# Assets Upload Failing

Tags: assets, file-uploads

I'm trying to upload some files to EE via Assets but they keep failing.

This is the response:

> Could not upload the file - server returned an unexpected response.
>   Please check the server settings.

And this is the response in Console:

> http://xxxxxxxx.co.uk/index.php?folder=4&ACT=20&qqfile=favicon.png
>   403 (Forbidden)

I've tried a few things...

- Changed permissions on folders (And sub folders) in my uploads folder to 777
- Changed permissions on Cache folder (And sub folders) to 777

I also double checked the upload path and upload URL and it's correct.

When I upload the files via FTP and then update the Indexes via Assets it syncs perfectly, but they won't upload via the CMS.

Any ideas?

Comment: htaccess file having an impact perhaps?

Comment: Possibly! I just noticed it's got index.php in the console but we're removing that in the URL.

Comment: have you set any of the Assets config overrides?

Comment: Assets doesn't ever respond with a 403 status, so it's either an .htaccess or module permission issue.